# ASP.Net MVC. How always include related data in Entity Framework queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

when selecting relational tables using Entity framework, we must manually 'include' the related data in the query, for instance:

```
MyEntity entity = db.MyEntities
            .Include(e => e.related_1)
            .Include(e => e.related_2)
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

otherwise the entity.related_1 or entity.related_2 will be null.

I would like to know if is there a way to set pre include relations before selecting it, without selecting related data everytime. for instance:

```
db.preInclude(???) // not a real method.
someOtherCode(...)
MyEntity  entity_1 = db.MyEntities.Find(id_1);
MyEntity  entity_2 = db.MyEntities.Find(id_2);
MyEntity  entity_3 = db.MyEntities.Find(id_3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your related virtual, so that enable Lazy loading, by this, you don't need to call Include explicitly, when you refer to this virtual related entity, it will be retrieved from database

Comment: How "virtual" attributes makes that difference?

Comment: make the related property virtual just enable Lazy loading

Comment: is it just a convention? or is there some logic?

Answer (score 1):

create a function that returns the query you want, then execute it:

```
public IQueryable getTheEntity(DbContext database) {
    var query = from e in database.MainEntity.Include("SubEntity1.Another").Include("SubEntity2");

    return query;
}
```

Then call that function whenever you need the full model:

```
using (MyDbContext database = new MyDbContext()) {
    var result = (from e in getTheEntity(database) where ...).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You can even make `getTheEntity(...)` an extension on your DbContext class so calling it is a little less verbose:

```
var result = (from e in database.getTheEntity() where ...).ToList();
```